# Fixing whatsapp click to chat on facebook browser on android

Tags: android, facebook, whatsapp

The click to chat integration for whatsapp is not working from facebooks own internal browser on android.

If you click on a link or shop now link on facebook, it opens the site using facebooks default internal browser, then you click on a whatsapp click to chat button, it will open a whatsapp site and ask if you want to send a message and then open the app store.

Has anyone found a way to bypass the facebook browser using some meta tag or code or found a proper undocumented whatsapp api call that works across all browsers?

I've tried with the official https://wa.me/phonenumber and https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber but both fail to open whatsapp and just open the app store instead.

On iphone it is working using the https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phonenumber version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the internal-application identifier for whatsapp?  For instance..

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

This is similar in format to `viber://`, `threema://`, and `sms:`.  By not using https/http, you identify the application you want to invoke.

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]

Comment: It's now been fixed in the browser, it seems completely bonkers that under the same "company" this would happen but it did...

Cheers!